# How to apply XML as a Search Criteria in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm passing the search criteria via XML in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SET @XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<search>
  <CustomerID></CustomerID>
  <CustomerName>Raj</CustomerName>
  <CustomerAddress></CustomerAddress>
</search>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

DECLARE @SEARCH_CRITERIA TABLE (CustomerID varchar(50) NULL, 
                                CustomerName varchar(50) NULL, 
                                CustomerAddress varchar(50) NULL)

INSERT INTO @SEARCH_CRITERIA
    SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'search')
    WITH 
        (CustomerID [varchar](50) 'CustomerID',
         CustomerName [varchar](100) 'CustomerName',
         CustomerAddress [varchar](100) 'CustomerAddress')

SELECT * 
FROM @SEARCH_CRITERIA
```

The Customer table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [cID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [cdob] [date] NULL,
    [cgender] [varchar](5) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([cID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data :

```
INSERT INTO Customer(cID, cName, cdob, cgender)
VALUES (1, 'Bala', '1986-02-14', 'M'); 

INSERT INTO Customer(cID, cName, cdob, cgender)
VALUES (2, 'Raj', '1982-05-24', 'M'); 

INSERT INTO Customer(cID, cName, cdob, cgender)
VALUES (3, 'Keerthi', '1990-06-06', 'F');
```

The `AddressInfo` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AddressInfo]
(
    [aID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [aAddress] [nvarchar](255) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Address] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([aID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,  
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data :

```
INSERT INTO AddressInfo(aID, cID, aAddress)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Bangalore, India');

INSERT INTO AddressInfo(aID, cID, aAddress)
VALUES (2, 2, 'Delhi, India');

INSERT INTO AddressInfo(aID, cID, aAddress)
VALUES (3, 3, 'Kochi, India');
```

Kindly assist me how to perform the search process.

My expected output:

Let us consider the above said XML, the `CustomerName` element has a value of **Raj**.

The output should be

```
    cID          cName          cdob          cgender          cAddress
___________________________________________________________________________
     2           Raj           1982-05-24      M              Delhi, India
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `sp_xml_preparedocument` at all. You could use `@nodes` like:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<search>
  <CustomerID></CustomerID>
  <CustomerName>Raj</CustomerName>
  <CustomerAddress></CustomerAddress>
</search>';

WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT   CustomerID      = s.c.value('CustomerID[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') 
           ,CustomerName    = s.c.value('CustomerName[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
           ,CustomerAddress = s.c.value('CustomerAddress[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
   FROM @XML.nodes('/search') s(c)
)
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, i.aAddress
FROM Customer c
JOIN AddressInfo i
  ON c.cID = i.cID
JOIN cte
  ON cte.CustomerID = c.cID
  OR cte.CustomerName = c.cName
  OR cte.CustomerAddress = i.aAddress;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/TVRRZ58907)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that you may change join condition to `LIKE` if you want partial match. `cte.CustomerName = c.cName` is exact match.

Second: If you need all search condition to be true at once, change `OR` to `AND`.

**EDIT:**

Partial match:

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT   
  CustomerID      = NULLIF(s.c.value('CustomerID[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),'')
  ,CustomerName    = NULLIF(s.c.value('CustomerName[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),'')
  ,CustomerAddress = NULLIF(s.c.value('CustomerAddress[1]','NVARCHAR(100)'),'')
 FROM @XML.nodes('/search') s(c)
)
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, i.aAddress
FROM Customer c
JOIN AddressInfo i
  ON c.cID = i.cID
JOIN cte
  ON cte.CustomerID = c.cID
  OR c.cName  LIKE '%' + cte.CustomerName + '%'
  OR i.aAddress LIKE '%' + cte.CustomerAddress + '%';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/JMFQG11068)**</kbd>

Note that `LIKE %...%` is not `SARGable` and it could has poor performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I give CutomerAddress as "Delhi", then it returns ZERO rows. Because the above code don't have a partial string match. Kindly assist me.